# Why is this simple F# code 36 times slower than C#/C++ versions?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, f#

I've written a simple test, which creates a variable, initializes it with zero and increments 100000000 times.

C++ does it in 0.36 s. Original C# version in 0.33s New in 0.8s  F# in 12 seconds.

I don't use any functions, so the problem is not with generics by default

F# code

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let N = 100000000
    let mutable x = 0
    let watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for i in seq{1..N} do
        x <- (x+1)
    printfn "%A" x
    printfn "%A" watch.Elapsed
    Console.ReadLine()
        |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

C++ code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int N = 100000000;
    int x = 0;
    double start = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    printf("%.4lf\n",(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SpeedTestCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int N = 100000000;
            int x = 0;
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0,N))
            //Originally it was for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
            {
                x = x + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Replacing `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` with `foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0,N))` makes C# program to run in about 0.8s, but it's still much faster than f#

**Edit**

Replaced `DateTime` with `StopWatch` the for F#/C#. Results are the same

Comment: Does C# slow down at all if you use `foreach` with `Enumerable.Range` instead of a simple for loop? I presume that's more like what F# is doing.

Comment: That seems very slow for C++ (I get 0.0000 on a macbook air). Did you compile with optimizations? Also, you should probably clock straight after the loop, not after a `printf`.

Comment: @juanchopanza  I compiled it with default Dev Cpp settings). printf doesn't affect much

Comment: @chris It slows down a bit, but is still 15 times faster than F#

Comment: @user2136963 Still, you shouldn't be timing a call to `printf`. Compile with optimizations on, there is no point comparing performance otherwise. After changing the output format, I get `0.00000200` for C++.

Comment: `for i in seq{1..n}` is always going to be crazy slow.  Also, for such short times, use stopwatch not datetime

Comment: @juanchopanza output format? @John Palmer But shouldn't it be equally slow to  `Enumerable.Range` given that `seq` masks `IEnumerable`? It's 15 times slower

Comment: @user2136963 The number of decimal places printed. The value is too small for `%.4lf`. You should really check how you're compiling this. Performance comparisons of non-optimized code are meaningless.

Comment: I suspect that `seq{1..n}` will actually create a sequence rather than being clever about it

Comment: Algorithmic complexity aside, source code is not fast or slow. Binaries executed on a computer are fast or slow. By presenting only code and not showing us how you translated the source code to binary code (i.e. compiler and compiler options), and not telling us the environment on which the binaries run, we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: @Christian Hackl Are you looking for some specific options? In F# Project, Properties-> Build has `Prefer 32 bit`, `Optimize code` and `Generate tail calls` enabled.  C# has `Prefer 32 bit`, and `Optimize code`

Comment: @user2136963: *All* options would be a good start. Or at least specifically list all non-default ones. And of course, the C++ compiler and linker options. And the environment on which the programs run.

Comment: BTW, the equivalent F# to the C++ loop would be `for i = 0 to N do`. (We should distinguish between the question on the `IEnumerable<>` performance between C# and F# and that on `for` loops.)

Comment: @user2136963 You really should get the output out of the measured times. This adds an unnecessary but enormous amount of uncertainty to your measurement.

Comment: FYI: This is being fixed as we speak :-) https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/931

Comment: Seriously, timing after output `(printf, Console.WriteLine, printfn)`... a really bad idea!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is very definitely happening directly as a consequence of using the expression:

```
for i in seq{1..N} do
```

On my machine, this gives the result:

> 100000000
>
> 00:00:09.1500924

If I change the loop to:

```
for i in 1..N do
```

The result changes dramatically:

> 100000000
>
> 00:00:00.1001864

**Why?**

The IL generated by these two approaches is quite different.  The second case, using the `1..N` syntax simply gets compiled the same way as a C# `for(int i=1; i<N+1; ++i)` loop.

The first case is quite different, this version produces a full sequence which is then enumerated by a foreach loop.

The C# and F# versions making use of `IEnumerables` differ in that they use different range functions to generate them.

The C# version uses `System.Linq.Enumerable.RangeIterator` to generate the value range, while the F# version uses `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32`.  I think it's safe to assume that the performance difference we're seeing between the C# and F# versions in this particular case are a result of the performance characteristics of these two functions.

svick is correct to point out in his comment that the `+` operator is actually being passed as an argument to the `integralRangeStep` function.

For the non-trivial case where `n <> m` this results in the F# compiler using a `ProperIntegralRangeEnumerator` with the implementation found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6463

```
let inline integralRangeStepEnumerator (zero,add,n,step,m,f) : IEnumerator<_> =
    // Generates sequence z_i where z_i = f (n + i.step) while n + i.step is in region (n,m)
    if n = m then
        new SingletonEnumerator<_> (f n) |> enumerator 
    else
        let up = (n < m)
        let canStart = not (if up then step < zero else step > zero) // check for interval increasing, step decreasing 
        // generate proper increasing sequence
        { new ProperIntegralRangeEnumerator<_,_>(n,m) with 
                member x.CanStart = canStart
                member x.Before a b = if up then (a < b) else (a > b)
                member x.Equal a b = (a = b)
                member x.Step a = add a step
                member x.Result a = f a } |> enumerator
```

We can see that stepping through the Enumerator results in calls to the supplied `add` function rather than a more straightforward, direct addition.

**Note:** All timings run in Release mode (Tail Calls: On, Optimisation: On).

Comment: [The implementation of `RangeInt32`](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/95fb299ab8588b112246f986148de9da8dbc9a4b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6579) looks like this: `let RangeInt32 n step m : seq<int> = integralRangeStep 0 (+) (n,step,m)`. Note that it uses `(+)` as a function value, which I think could certainly account for the performance difference.

Comment: @user2136963 What do you get when you implement this?

Comment: @cst1992 Currently, my stopwatch shows 8s with `seq{1..N}` and 0.6s with `1..N`

Answer (score 15):

I don't know F# very well so I wanted to take a peek at the code it produces. Here's the result. It just confirms TheInnerLight's answer.

First, C++ should be able to optimize your `for` loop away, you'll get a zero (or near-zero) time. The .NET compilers and JIT currently don't perform this optimization, so let's compare them.

Here's the IL of the C# loop:

```
// [21 28 - 21 58]
IL_000e: ldc.i4.0     
IL_000f: ldc.i4       100000000
IL_0014: call         class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Range(int32, int32)
IL_0019: callvirt     instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0/*int32*/> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
IL_001e: stloc.2      // V_2
.try
{

  IL_001f: br.s         IL_002c

// [21 16 - 21 24]
  IL_0021: ldloc.2      // V_2
  IL_0022: callvirt     instance !0/*int32*/ class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
  IL_0027: pop          

// [22 9 - 22 15]
  IL_0028: ldloc.0      // num1
  IL_0029: ldc.i4.1     
  IL_002a: add          
  IL_002b: stloc.0      // num1

  IL_002c: ldloc.2      // V_2
  IL_002d: callvirt     instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
  IL_0032: brtrue.s     IL_0021
  IL_0034: leave.s      IL_0040
} // end of .try
finally
{
  IL_0036: ldloc.2      // V_2
  IL_0037: brfalse.s    IL_003f
  IL_0039: ldloc.2      // V_2
  IL_003a: callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
  IL_003f: endfinally   
} // end of finally
```

And here's the IL of the F# loop:

```
// [23 5 - 23 138]
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1     
IL_0010: ldc.i4.1     
IL_0011: ldc.i4       100000000
IL_0016: call         class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators/OperatorIntrinsics::RangeInt32(int32, int32, int32)
IL_001b: call         class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0/*int32*/> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators::CreateSequence<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0/*int32*/>)
IL_0020: stloc.2      // V_2
IL_0021: ldloc.2      // V_2
IL_0022: callvirt     instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0/*int32*/> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
IL_0027: stloc.3      // enumerator
.try
{

// [26 7 - 26 36]
  IL_0028: ldloc.3      // enumerator
  IL_0029: callvirt     instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
  IL_002e: brfalse.s    IL_003f

// [28 9 - 28 41]
  IL_0030: ldloc.3      // enumerator
  IL_0031: callvirt     instance !0/*int32*/ class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
  IL_0036: stloc.s      current

// [29 9 - 29 15]
  IL_0038: ldloc.0      // func
  IL_0039: ldc.i4.1     
  IL_003a: add          
  IL_003b: stloc.0      // func
  IL_003c: nop          

  IL_003d: br.s         IL_0028
  IL_003f: ldnull       
  IL_0040: stloc.s      V_4
  IL_0042: leave.s      IL_005d
} // end of .try
finally
{

// [34 7 - 34 57]
  IL_0044: ldloc.3      // enumerator
  IL_0045: isinst       [mscorlib]System.IDisposable
  IL_004a: stloc.s      disposable

// [35 7 - 35 30]
  IL_004c: ldloc.s      disposable
  IL_004e: brfalse.s    IL_005a

// [36 9 - 36 29]
  IL_0050: ldloc.s      disposable
  IL_0052: callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()

  IL_0057: ldnull       
  IL_0058: pop          
  IL_0059: endfinally   
  IL_005a: ldnull       
  IL_005b: pop          
  IL_005c: endfinally   
} // end of finally
IL_005d: ldloc.s      V_4
IL_005f: pop
```

So, while the loops are a bit different, they mainly do the same thing.

Here's what C# does:

- [0] Branch to the `MoveNext` part (just once)
- [1] Get the `Current` property of the enumerable, **and discard it**
- [2] Add 1 to the local `0`
- [3] Call `MoveNext`
- [4] Go back to [1] on `true`, or exit the loop on `false`

The F# loop does the following:

- [0] Call `MoveNext`
- [1] Leave the loop on `false`
- [2] Get the `Current` property of the enumerable, **and store its value in a local**
- [3] Add 1 to the local `0`
- [4] Take a break with `nop` *(sic)*
- [5] Branch to [0]

So we have two differences here:

- C# discards the `Current` property's value while F# stores it in a local
- F# has a `nop` (do nothing) instruction in the loop for some reason that's beyond me (and yes, this is Release mode).

But these differences alone don't explain the huge performance impact. Let's take a look at what the JIT does with this.

*Note:* `rcx` is the first argument in the x64 calling convention used, which corresponds to the `this` implicit parameter in instance method calls.

C#, x64:

```
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, N))
00007FFCF2B94514  xor         ecx,ecx  
00007FFCF2B94516  mov         edx,5F5E100h  
00007FFCF2B9451B  call        00007FFD50EF08F0          // Call Enumerable.Range
00007FFCF2B94520  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FFCF2B94523  mov         r11,7FFCF2A80040h
00007FFCF2B9452D  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B9452F  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call GetEnumerator
00007FFCF2B94532  mov         qword ptr [rbp-20h],rax  
00007FFCF2B94536  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]   // Store the IEnumerator in rcx
00007FFCF2B9453A  mov         r11,7FFCF2A80048h        
00007FFCF2B94544  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B94546  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call MoveNext
00007FFCF2B94549  test        al,al  
00007FFCF2B9454B  je          00007FFCF2B9457F          // Skip the loop
00007FFCF2B9454D  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]   // Store the IEnumerator in rcx
00007FFCF2B94551  mov         r11,7FFCF2A80050h  
00007FFCF2B9455B  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B9455D  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call get_Current
            {
                x = x + 1;
00007FFCF2B94560  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-0Ch]  
00007FFCF2B94563  inc         ecx                       
00007FFCF2B94565  mov         dword ptr [rbp-0Ch],ecx  
            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, N))
00007FFCF2B94568  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]   // Store the IEnumerator in rcx
00007FFCF2B9456C  mov         r11,7FFCF2A80048h  
00007FFCF2B94576  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B94578  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call MoveNext
00007FFCF2B9457B  test        al,al  
00007FFCF2B9457D  jne         00007FFCF2B9454D  
00007FFCF2B9457F  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+20h]  
00007FFCF2B94584  call        00007FFCF2B945C6  
00007FFCF2B94589  nop  
            }
```

F#, x64:

```
    for i in seq{1..N} do
00007FFCF2B904F4  mov         ecx,1  
00007FFCF2B904F9  mov         edx,1  
00007FFCF2B904FE  mov         r8d,5F5E100h  
00007FFCF2B90504  call        00007FFD42AA2B80          // Create the sequence
00007FFCF2B90509  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FFCF2B9050C  mov         r11,7FFCF2A90020h  
00007FFCF2B90516  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B90518  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call GetEnumerator
00007FFCF2B9051B  mov         qword ptr [rbp-20h],rax  
00007FFCF2B9051F  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]   // Store the IEnumerator in rcx
00007FFCF2B90523  mov         r11,7FFCF2A90028h  
00007FFCF2B9052D  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B9052F  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call MoveNext  
00007FFCF2B90532  test        al,al  
00007FFCF2B90534  je          00007FFCF2B90553          // Exit the loop?
        x <- (x+1)
00007FFCF2B90536  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]  
00007FFCF2B9053A  mov         r11,7FFCF2A90030h  
00007FFCF2B90544  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFCF2B90546  call        qword ptr [r11]           // Call get_Current
00007FFCF2B90549  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbp-0Ch]  
00007FFCF2B9054C  inc         edx  
00007FFCF2B9054E  mov         dword ptr [rbp-0Ch],edx  
00007FFCF2B90551  jmp         00007FFCF2B9051F          // Loop
00007FFCF2B90553  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+20h]  
00007FFCF2B90558  call        00007FFCF2B9061C  
00007FFCF2B9055D  nop
```

First, we notice that C# *still* calls `Current` even though it discards its result. This is a virtual call, which didn't get optimized away.

Oh and that F# `nop` IL opcode is optimized away by the JIT. There is a `nop` in the x64 code, but it's *after* the loop, and it's certainly here for purposes of alignment.

Then, we can see the code is very similar in the two cases, although it's structured a bit differently. It calls the same functions and doesn't do anything weird.

So yes, the performance difference you're seeing is certainly explained by the way F# constructs its sequence, not by its looping mechanism itself.

Comment: I am always appreciative of answers involving assembly code! Good job.

Answer (score 10):

As a person that have dug around in the F# compiler around these parts I thought I perhaps can share some lights on what is going on inside the F# compiler.

As many noted `for i in seq{1..N}` creates an `IEnumerable<>` over the range `1..N`. Iterating over `IEnumerable<>` is kind of slow partly because of virtual calls to `Current` and `MoveNext`. In principle it's possible for F# to detect this pattern and optimize it but currently F# doesn't.

A suggestion is to use the pattern `for i in 1..N` which gives much better performance as well as reduced GC pressure.

A question to the reader before reading on is what kind of performance can we expect from the expressions:

- `for i in 1L..int64 N`
- `for i in 1..2..N`

When the F# [type checker](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/TypeChecker.fs) detects a `for-each expression` it convert it into a more primitive expression that can more readily be converted into a IL code. The fallback case is to convert the `for-each expression` into something like this:

```
// body is the body of the for_each expression, enumerable is what we iterate over
let for_each (body : 'T -> unit) (enumerable : IEnumerable<'T>) : unit =
  let e = enumerable.GetEnumerator ()
  try
    while e.MoveNext () do
      body e.Current
  finally
    e.Dispose ()
```

This happens in the function `TcForEachExpr`. The curious reader notices this line in this function:

```
// optimize 'for i in n .. m do' 
| Expr.App(Expr.Val(vf,_,_),_,[tyarg],[startExpr;finishExpr],_) 
    when valRefEq cenv.g vf cenv.g.range_op_vref && typeEquiv cenv.g tyarg cenv.g.int_ty -> 
        (cenv.g.int32_ty, (fun _ x -> x), id, Choice1Of3 (startExpr,finishExpr))
```

The type checker is actually performing an optimization of `for-each expression` of the shape `for i in lowerint32..upperinter32`. One would think a more naturally place would be to do this in the [optimizer](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/Optimizer.fs). I suspect this is for legacy reasons when F# wasn't as mature as all new optimizations has to go into the optimizer. Unfortunately moving this optimization to the optimizer is not easily done as this would change the shape of expression tree for `<@ for i in 0..100 @>` most likely breaking lots of user code code. For the same reason no more optimizations can be added to the type checker. This is the joy and challenge of maintaining backwards compatibility.

The optimization code also allows us to answer the previous questions:

- `for i in 1L..int64 N` - Optimization will not apply because it requires int32
- `for i in 1..2..N`- Optimization will not apply because no case for `range_step_op_vref`

What the fallback case will do then is creating a `seq` object around the range expression and iterate over that using `.Current/.MoveNext`. It will work but the performance will be poor.

There's also an optimization for iterating over arrays:

```
// optimize 'for i in arr do' 
| _ when isArray1DTy cenv.g enumExprTy  -> 
    let arrVar,arrExpr = mkCompGenLocal m "arr" enumExprTy
    let idxVar,idxExpr = mkCompGenLocal m "idx" cenv.g.int32_ty
    let elemTy = destArrayTy cenv.g enumExprTy
```

So iterating over arrays will be quick (just as it is in C#) but what about strings (which is fast in C#) or other datastructures?

It turns out that the optimizer has more cases where it detects iteration over strings, fsharp lists and for loops with increments of 1 & -1 and converts them into efficient `for loops` (most of which happens in `DetectAndOptimizeForExpression`).

Code demonstrating some of the optimizations or missed opportunities for optimizations discussed

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let total = 10000000
let outer = 10
let inner = total / outer

let stopWatch = 
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  sw

let timeIt (name : string) (a : unit -> 'T) : unit = // ' 
  let t = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
  let v = a ()
  for i = 1 to (outer - 1) do
    a () |> ignore
  let d = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - t
  printfn "%s, elapsed %d ms, result %A" name d v

let case1 () = 
  // Slow because it fallbacks into slow but safe code pattern
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in seq{1..inner} do
    x <- x+1
  x

let case2 () = 
  // Fast because the optimization in TypeChecker.fs matches
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in 1..inner do
    x <- x+1
  x

let case3 () = 
  // Slow because the optimization in TypeChecker.fs requires int32
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in 1L..int64 inner do
    x <- x+1
  x

let case4 () = 
  // Slow because the optimization in TypeChecker.fs doesn't recognize b..inc..e patterns
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in 1..2..inner do
    x <- x+1
  x

let case5 () = 
  // Fast because Optimizer.fs recognizes this pattern
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in 1..1..inner do
    x <- x+1
  x

let case6 () = 
  // Fast because Optimizer.fs recognizes this pattern
  let mutable x = 0
  for i in inner..(-1)..1 do
    x <- x+1
  x


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  timeIt "case1" case1
  timeIt "case2" case2
  timeIt "case3" case3
  timeIt "case4" case4
  timeIt "case5" case5
  timeIt "case6" case6

  0
```

I would like to encourage anyone that thinks they have a valueable improvement to the F# optimizer to download the F# code and try to apply it. Well-done optimizations are almost always welcome.

Hope this was interesting to someone

Comment: Lucas Trzesniewski as well as comparison with `Enumerable.Range` showed that the problem is in construction of enumerable itself, not virtual method calls. Do you have some insights on why `seq{}` and `Enumerable.Range` are implemented so differently?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of how F# implements a lazy sequence over a range it seems to use `RangeInt32` which in turn inherit `ProperIntegralRangeEnumerator` which in turn inherit `BaseRangeEnumerator` which finally implements `IEnumerator<>`. During call to `MoveNext` there's lot of validation and checking using virtual calls. If one were to make a specialized `RangeEnumerator` as there seems to be for C# one probably see a significant improvement in speed. A tail-recursive function that just incremented an int would still crush it though.

Comment: It might interest you that in my experience if one avoid performance traps in C# and F# and tries to write the most efficient function F# quite often comes out on top. Partly thanks to the inline keyword and `tail-call` elimination

Answer (score 6):

I think what is happening is that the extra `seq` is preventing some optimizations.

If you change to

```
for i in 1..N
```

which I think is pretty much equivalent (at least to the c++) it is much much faster